# How to add axes numbers to matplotlib plot?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

If I have this plot below, how do I add the coordinates (29.05,-93.68) next to the (0,0)? So i would like to include the coordinates with the (0,0) and the bottom left corner. I have tried:

```
import matplotlib.axes as axes
axes.Axes.set_xlim(left=-93.86,right=None)
axes.Axes.set_ylim(bottom=-29.05,top=None)
```

But I keep getting an error. I also don't think that is the correct method to include both points. Any suggestions?
[image]

Comment: So first of all, a [mcve] would be helpful to understand what you're doing. Then I don't understand what "include a point" means in terms of the resulting plot. How would a plot look like where I have "included a point"? Concerning the error, this is surely because you should call the `.set_xlim` method of the axes *instance* you plot to, i.e. the `ax` you may have somewhere in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as as plt
fig, ax = plt.subplots()    
ax.set_xlim(-93.86, 22.5)
ax.set_ylim(-29.05, 20)
```